# Adding attributes to parent class fields and properties

Tags: c#-4.0

In my example to illustrate my use case I have a parent class that is purposely database agnostic (let's say I can't change the code of it for some reasons, because the class come from a commercial assembly or the .net framework or are auto generated by entity framework):

```
public class Father
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
}
```

Now I'd like to store an object derived from it into MongoDB (again, it's only for the example, there a lot of other use cases and my question has nothing to do with MongoDB):

```
public class Child:Father
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public DateTime DateCreation;
}
```

But I'd like to add attributes to some elements of the father, like [BsonIgnoreIfNull], *without* overriding (they are not marked as virtual) or having to fully reimplement the Father in my Child class.

What would be the cleanest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at creating your own attributes?

Comment: The point is to add attributes to the father fields and properties, I don't see how creating my own attributes can solve this in any way, the problem would remain the same.

Comment: I have the same problem, deriving from .net internal class ApplicationUser, I want one of the members to be with [Required] attribute. In my case they are marked virtual so i can override them to solve the problem.